# Do I need to install Git for both Windows 10 and WSL?

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up a web development environment using a [guide on Medium](https://medium.com/@mfosullivan/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-a-modern-web-development-environment-on-windows-10-4d75cd94cde8). The author says we need to install Git for both Windows and for Windows Subsystem for Linux. Git takes up a lot of space. Do we need to install it twice?

I have Visual Studio Code and Ubuntu (WSL). I also installed Git for Windows 10.

Comment: Ubuntu as every other Linux distro comes pre-installed with git and many other useful softwares. If you use git in WSL then it is already there, otherwise if you need to use it directly from vs code, you need to install it in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) differs from the [Linux Git](https://git-scm.com/download/linux).

So, if you want to execute commands in a Windows CMD *and* a Linux WSL shell, then yes, you would need to install both.

On Windows side, that can mean simply uncompressing the self-extracting archive [`PortableGit-2.22.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.22.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.22.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add it to your PATH.